# What is the workflow for adding details to low poly to bake using normals

Tags: modeling, uv, texture-baking, retopology

I'm attempting to add sort of hard surface modelling details to an existing model in counter strike. So far I have imported the model provided by valve, added the details I want and now need to bake these onto the uv provided by valve. [image: image of added details]

Here is the topology.
[image]

I have tried to bake these details onto the original low poly model provided by valve but I am getting all sorts of errors. I am new to 3d modelling so am I missing something major here. I have a feeling its something to do with the fact that the topology of the original model and my added details are not joined together so its having trouble working out how to bake the normals. I am completely lost so any help would be great cheers.

Here is the original model for reference: [image]